# ror: Belongs_to has_many doesn't do the foreign key check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, has-many, belongs-to

i'm really new in ruby on rails and i need a hand here. In my models i have documents and conversion_details:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :origin_details, :class_name => "ConversionDetails", :foreign_key => "origin_id"
    has_many :destination_details, :class_name => "ConversionDetails", :foreign_key => "destination_id"
    attr_accessible :extension, :name, :text
end

class ConversionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :origin, :class_name => "Documents"
    belongs_to :destination, :class_name => "Documents"
    attr_accessible :conversionDate, :requestMsg, :responseMsg, :status, :origin_id, :destination_id
end
```

each conversionDetail has an origin document and a one or many documents associated.
Mi questions are:

1) this models are fine? because i can't do a migration with "rails g migration .... docuemnt:reference document:reference" twice

2) when i go to rails console and i do: ConversionDetail.create(origin_id:500,destination_id:1000) the conversion its created BUT it shouldn't because i don't have in documents any id with that's numbers

Please help me, i will be grateful. Thanks to all, you are the best!

PD: Sorry for my really bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting rails to define the foreign key constraint in the database. Rails doesn't do this. The `foreign_key` on associations simply indicates which database column is to be used to look up the associated records.

Comment: So this means that there isn't a way to restrict the entry of a row of documents that has a row with a wrong user_id?

PD: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: You would have to do it with validations. You could validate that the id is for a conversion detail that exists.

Comment: Thank you Shadwell. i would love to give you a positive score but i can't because my reputation is too small. Thanks again!